# How to enabled CGLIB proxies on @Component?

Tags: java, spring-boot, proxies

I'm seeing an error in my SpringBoot Application after using the micrometer `@Timed` annotation.

```
Bean named 'XXXX' is expected to be of type 'xxxx.XXXX' but was actually of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy223'
```

This is novel to me, but I'm now aware of the difference between JDK and CGLIB proxies.

In terms of a soluton the first option is to use an `Interface`. But, as I'm timing `private` methods, I'm hesitant to take this approach. That means `CGLIB` proxies or switching away from `@Timed` and toward `registry.timer(...)`.

I've come across [EnableAspectJAutoProxy](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/EnableAspectJAutoProxy.html) but it's usage is not clear to me for a `@Component`. Should it just work once it's set on my `@Configuration` or `@SpringBootApplication` classes? Neither of which have worked.