# How to debug when a JDK or CGLIB dynamic proxy will be used in Java by Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dynamic-proxy

I've hit an issue where adding an annotation to a class produces a proxy error

> Bean named 'XXXX' is expected to be of type 'xxxx.XXXX' but was actually of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy223'

For further details see [How to enabled CGLIB proxies on @Component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73127163/how-to-enabled-cglib-proxies-on-component)

I'm trying to understand when Java will decided to create a JDK or CGLIB proxy. I understand it's meant to create JDK proxies when there's an interface and CGLIB proxies otherwise. Plus SpringBoot 2.0+ is meant to always use CGLIB proxies. See https://www.springcloud.io/post/2022-01/springboot-aop/#gsc.tab=0

However in my case I'm getting a JDK proxy when there is no interface. As such I'd like to figure out where the code makes this decision in order to debug it.

Potentially this is done by a implementation of [AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/framework/autoproxy/AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.html). But actually finding the point at which the decision is taken is time consuming. Even with a debugger at hand.

Any pointers?

Comment: `I understand it's meant to create JDK proxies when there's an interface and CGLIB proxies otherwise` - that is not correct, however not far from the truth. The Q: is it possible to create CGLIB proxy if target class is final?

Comment: In this case the class was not `final`. It does have a `static final` class field.

Answer (score 0):

I found, hidden away in our `Configuration` hierarchy, the following bean definition.

```
@Bean
public AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator aspectJProxyCreator() {
    return new AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator();
}
```

This appears to be the source of the problem. Which is impressive as my `Component` named `XXXX` is not an interface and does not implement one. i.e. That means a JDK proxy should not be used.

If I switch the bean definition over to

```
@Bean
public AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator aspectJProxyCreator() {
    var a = new AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator();
    // Fixes the problem
    a.setProxyTargetClass(true);
    return a;
}
```

A `CGLIB` proxy is instead created. A better solution would be to remove this bean entirely, which I'm investigating.